# Connecting to RabbitMQ

Tags: scala, connection-pool, rabbitmq

I would like a review for this connection to RabbitMQ. I just developed it and seems to be working well, but I would like another set of eyes on it before putting this on the sever.

```
package models

import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory
import com.rabbitmq.client.MessageProperties

import anorm.SQL
import anorm.sqlToSimple
import anorm.toParameterValue
import play.api.Play.current

object RabbitMQConnection {
  private var connection: Connection = null
  def getConnection(ss:Connection): Connection = {
    println(ss+"  connection <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<")
    connection=ss
    connection match {
      case null => {
        val factory = new ConnectionFactory()
        println("waiting for new connection")
        factory.setHost("172.22.22.222")
        println("host setted")
        connection = factory.newConnection()
        println("connection created")
        connection
      }
      case _ =>{
        println("connection is not null")
        connection
      }
    }
  }
}

object RMQ {
  var connection = RabbitMQConnection.getConnection(null)

  def setQ(qName: String, message: String) = {
    println("ping received")
    try {
      println(connection)
      if (connection != null) {
        if (connection.isOpen()) {
          println("connection is open")
        } else {
          connection = RabbitMQConnection.getConnection(null)
          println("connection is new "+connection)
        }
        println("connetion is ready to use")
        val channel = connection.createChannel()
        channel.queueDeclare(qName, true, false, false, null) //suggestion 
        channel.basicPublish("", qName, MessageProperties.PERSISTENT_TEXT_PLAIN, message.getBytes())
        println("status" + channel.close())
        println("setQ complete executed for " + qName)
        Map("result" -> "success")

      } else {
        println("connection can't established to rabbit mq for =>" + qName)
        LogFile.QLogs(qName, message)
        Map("result" -> "error")
      }
    } catch {
      case e: Exception =>
        println(e.printStackTrace())
        println("Rabbit Mq Server is Down for =>" + qName)
        LogFile.QLogs(qName, message)
        Map("result" ->"error")
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

Well, the first thing I would recommend is replacing all of those `println` statements with some kind of logging. In any kind of production environment, logging is something that needs more thought and care so that it is useful, without consuming resources unnecessarily. Or, if they're just for the original developer during development, maybe delete them.

I find the structure of this code to be rather odd. For all the trappings of OO programming, what you essentially have is two global public functions and one global public variable.

The function name `setQ` doesn't seem to say what you're actually doing - which appears to be creating a channel and publishing a message to it. `publishMessage` would make more sense, I think.

All of the code that checks the usability of the connection should be extracted into a single function, something along the lines of `haveUsableConnection` - the two if/else blocks are making it hard to see the code that is actually doing the work.

I question the hard coded IP address. Magic numbers and magic strings are frequently a bad idea.

Answer (score 4):

- Don't use `null`, but instead `Option[Connection]`.  `null` is frowned upon in Scala.
- It looks quite odd that `getConnection(ss:Connection)` takes in a `Connection`.  That method either sets the connection (opposite of get!), or initialize and returns the connection if the argument is null.  Create two different methods.  It does not make much sense as it is... it looks like you just wanted to use pattern matching somewhere.
- You can get rid of the whole object `RabbitMQConnection` and replace your lazy initialization of the connection with the Scala `lazy` keyword.  (EDIT: actually, it is not clear what exactly you should do with the connection, since you also have to always check if it is still open.  I'll let you figure this out, but you should be aware of Scala's `lazy`.)
- Since `setQ` only needs the `connection` to create a `Channel`, I would just have a method to fetch the `Channel`.  That method would check if the `Connection` is open and restart it if needed.   (Separation of concerns.)
- I hope all the `println` are just for debugging and will be removed.  If you keep those, use some logging service instead, even if it just prints to console in the end.  More generally, you should strive for separation of concerns and find a way to separate the code that actually does something and the logging code.
- I would declare the return type of `setQ`.
- About that return type: instead of `Map("result" -> "success")` and `Map("result" ->"error")` use Scala's [`Try`](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.util.Try).  `Try` is actually a monad so you'll be able to call `map` and `flatMap` on the result of `setQ`.

Answer (score -2):

To connect with RabbitMQ using C# code kindly follow below steps.

1. You should have valid Host Name that you may get it from RabbitMQ URL
2. Virtual Domain name
3. User name and Password if you are connecting with remote RabbitMQ server

Please see below code,

```
using RabbitMQ.Client;
using RabbitMQ.Client.Events;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
namespace RMQConnect
{
public class RabbitMQQueueManager
   {   
       private const string ORIGINAL_QUEUENAME_KEY = "originalQueueName";
      private const ushort PREFETCH_SIZE = 50;

    public IConnection GetRabbitMqConnection()
    {
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory
        {
            HostName = "d1vmrmqtrv01.oldev.arol.shell.com",
            VirtualHost = "TRV_ANDD",
            UserName = "ol_sqlmaint_trv",
            Password = "P@ssw0rd",

        };
        return factory.CreateConnection();
    }

    public List<Message> GetMessagesFromQueueNoAck(string queueName, int 
    messageCount = -1)
    {
        QueueingBasicConsumer consumer = null;
        var responseMessages = new List<Message>();
        BasicDeliverEventArgs result = null;
        using (var rmqConnection = GetRabbitMqConnection())
        {
            using (var channel = rmqConnection.CreateModel())
            {
                try
                {
                    var queueMessageCount = (int)channel.MessageCount(queueName);
                    var count = messageCount > -1 ? messageCount <= 
                    queueMessageCount ? messageCount : queueMessageCount : 
                    queueMessageCount;
                var pfCount = count >= PREFETCH_SIZE ? PREFETCH_SIZE : count;
                channel.BasicQos(0, (ushort)pfCount, false);
                consumer = new QueueingBasicConsumer(channel);
                channel.BasicConsume(queueName, false, consumer);
                for (int i = 0; i < pfCount; i++)
                {
                    if (!channel.IsOpen)
                    {
                        throw new ApplicationException("Channel is closed");
                    }
                    result = consumer.Queue.Dequeue();
                    try
                    {
                        string messageData = 
                        System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result.Body);
                        var rMessage = new Message(messageData);
                        rMessage.Header = new MessageHeader();



    RmqHeaderHandler.ReadRmqMessageProperties(result.BasicProperties, rMessage);
                        channel.BasicNack(result.DeliveryTag, false, true);                         
                        responseMessages.Add(rMessage);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {     
                        channel.BasicNack(result.DeliveryTag, false, true);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                ////Nack the message back to queue in case of exception
                if (result != null)
                {
                    channel.BasicNack(result.DeliveryTag, false, true);
                }
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
    return responseMessages;
    } 
   }
    public static class RmqHeaderHandler
    {
    private const byte NonPersistentDeliveryMode = 1;
  private const byte PersistentDeliveryMode = 2;
   private const string SecurityTokenKey = "SecurityToken";
  private const string Properties = "properties";
  private const string MessageNameKey = "MessageName";
  private const string SystemPropertiesKey = "SystemProperties";
  private const string ApplicationPropertiesKey = "ApplicationProperties";
  #region Public Methods
   public static void ReadDynamicMessageProperties(dynamic messageProperties, 
   Message message)
   {
      try
      {
          message.Header.AppId = messageProperties.appId;
          message.Header.MessageId = messageProperties.messageId;
          message.Header.GeneratedAtUtc = messageProperties.generatedAtUtc;
          message.Header.ExpirationInMilliseconds = 
          messageProperties.expirationInMilliseconds;
          message.Header.IsPersistent = messageProperties.isPersistent;
          message.Header.Delete = Convert.ToBoolean(messageProperties.delete);
          message.Header.Move = Convert.ToBoolean(messageProperties.move);
          if (messageProperties.ContainsKey("messageName"))
        {
            message.Header.MessageName = messageProperties.messageName;
        }
        if (messageProperties.ContainsKey("properties"))
        {
            var customProperties = 
        Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>> 
       (Convert.ToString(messageProperties.properties));
            foreach (var propPair in customProperties)
            {
                message.Header.Properties.Add(propPair.Key, propPair.Value);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
public static void ReadRmqMessageProperties(IBasicProperties messageProperties, 
Message message)
{
    //message.Header.AppId = messageProperties.AppId;
    message.Header.MessageId = messageProperties.MessageId;
    message.Header.GeneratedAtUtc = new 
    DateTime(messageProperties.Timestamp.UnixTime);
    message.Header.ExpirationInMilliseconds = messageProperties.Expiration;
    message.Header.IsPersistent = messageProperties.DeliveryMode == 
    PersistentDeliveryMode;
    if (messageProperties.Headers!=null && 
     messageProperties.Headers.ContainsKey(SystemPropertiesKey))
    {
        var systemProperties = 
        DeserializeMessageProperties((byte[])
      messageProperties.Headers[SystemPropertiesKey]);
        if (systemProperties.ContainsKey(MessageNameKey))
        {
            message.Header.MessageName = systemProperties[MessageNameKey];
        }
    }
    if (messageProperties.Headers!=null && 
     messageProperties.Headers.ContainsKey(ApplicationPropertiesKey))
    {
        var applicationProperties = 
       DeserializeMessageProperties((byte[])
       messageProperties.Headers[ApplicationPropertiesKey]);
        foreach (var propPair in applicationProperties)
        {
            message.Header.Properties.Add(propPair.Key, propPair.Value);
        }
    }
}
#endregion
#region private methods
private static Dictionary<string, string> DeserializeMessageProperties(byte[] 
  properties)
{
    //var serializer = new .JsonMessageSerializer();
    var serializedText = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(properties);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>> 
   (serializedText);
 }
#endregion
}
public class QueueInfoModel
{
    public string Environment { get; set; }
  public string ApplicationGroup { get; set; }
  public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
public string ErrorQueueName { get; set; }
public string OriginalQueueName { get; set; }
public int MessageCount { get; set; }
}
  [Serializable]
  public class MessageHeader
 {
     public MessageHeader()
     {
        this.MessageId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        this.Properties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        this.IsPersistent = true;
    }
    public string AppId { get; set; }
    public string MessageId { get; set; }
    public string MessageName { get; set; }
    public DateTime GeneratedAtUtc { get; set; }
    public string ExpirationInMilliseconds { get; set; }
    public bool IsPersistent { get; set; }
    public bool Delete { get; set; }
    public bool Move { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, string> Properties { get; private set; }
 }
[Serializable]
 public class Message
{
    private readonly string serializableBody;
    public Message(string serializableBody)
    {
        this.serializableBody = serializableBody;
    }
public MessageHeader Header
{
    get;
    set;
}
public string MessageBody
{
    get
    {
        return this.serializableBody;
    }
}
public byte[] GetBody()
{
    return (byte[])((object)Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(this.MessageBody));
   }
 }

 }
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly this is not a review but an alternative version without a review. If you think that OP makes something _incorrectly_ then please summarize it in your answer and show where your code _improves_ it.